# How to cross compile Go to 32 bit windows .exe

Tags: go, cgo

I need to compile a set of Go + C code into both 64 bit and 32 bit exe under my 64 bit windows system. My compiler is TDM-GCC-64 9.2.0. The compilation was smooth for 64 bits and a .exe file was created.

But the compilation failed after I set

$Env:GOARCH = 386

to get a 32 bit exe file. The error msg was "main.go:4:2: build constraints exclude all Go files in C:\Users\xxx\test\src". The directory \src contains a test c function and go function to call c.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you having trouble understanding this error message? Does your code use build constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I figured out it is key to set up four relevant env variables properly, the 32 bit program can be compiled smoothly.

```
$env:GOOS="windows"
$env:GOARCH="386" 
$env:CGO_ENABLED=1
$env:GOGCCFLAGS="-m32 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0"
go build -x -buildmode=c-shared -o xxx.so main.go
```

Comment: Did this generate a windows DLL?
I am trying to build a 32bit windows DLL on windows (64bit) and but I get the following error: -buildmode=c-shared not supported on "windows"/"386"